How may I show $\sum_{d \mid n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)} = \frac{n}{\phi(n)}$?
I wish to show the identity
$$\sum_{d \mid n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)} = \frac{n}{\phi(n)},$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function defined by
$$\mu(n) = \begin{cases}(-1)^k & \text{$n=p_1 \dots p_k$, the $p_i$s distinct primes} \\ 0 & \text{$n$ is not squarefree}\end{cases}$$
and $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

I'm aware of the fact that the Dirichlet convolution operation $\ast$ defined by
$$(f \ast g) (n) := \sum_{d | n} f(d)g(n/d)$$
is commutative, associative, and that if $f, g$ are multiplicative, then so is $f \ast g$ (presumably useful in this case as $\mu$ and $\phi$ can both be shown to be multiplicative.)
We also have the Möbius formula $f(n) = \sum_{d | n} g(d)$ implies $g(n) = \mu \ast f$.

I've been playing around with the above facts for a while but am unable to make any progress. Can someone give some guidance?

Is the left hand multiplicative?  If so, it suffices to prove it for prime powers.

Yes, the functions are multiplicative. So we can prove it as in the duplicate (which also has more answers).
